# Loop grande dentrou de outros

Tags: c#, lógica, loop

O desafio consiste em achar x maneiras diferentes de dividir o objeto, para 3 pessoas em que cada uma tem que receber um valor menor ou igual a M, e a soma do valor que cada um ganhou tem que ser igual a N, Segue abaixo o codigo que fiz:

```
int m,n;
m = 98765;
n = 100000;

for (int i = m; i > 0; i--)
            {
                for (int j = m; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    for (int b = m; b > 0; b--)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i + "   " + j + "    " + b);
                        if (i + j + b == n)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(somas++);
                           /* As linhas abaixo são para observar como decorre o programa */
                            Console.WriteLine(i + "   " + j + "    " + b);//
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
```

no entanto, para os valores especificados de N e M, o projeto demorara MUITO tempo para dar o resultado, existe alguma forma, de simplificar isso, algum teorema, ou algo assim, algo que fizesse ir mais rapido. Obrigado

Comment: [Fiz esse teste aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VROQ2a) e acho que está imprimindo errado. Ou não entendi o que vai em i, j e b.

Comment: i, j e b, são os numeros da divisão dos objetos entre as 3 pessoas, vamos supor que a divisão pra cada aluno tenho que ser menor q 34 e a soma da quantidade de cada objeto que cada pessoa tem vai ser 100: 34 + 34 + 32 = 100, ou seja i + j + b = 100, essas variaveis são usadas para verificar se o a divisão corresponde a regras

Comment: [link de onde tirei o desafio](http://olimpiada.ic.unicamp.br/pratique/programacao/nivel2/2015f1p2_caixinha), creio que isso possa lhe ajudar a entender o contexto

Comment: Pode colocar qual é a resposta certa na pergunta? Numa matemática apressada obtive 2.287.837.

Comment: Sim, mas então, você viu que no exemplo que coloquei começo imprimindo 98, 98 e 98?

Comment: @BrunoCosta, para os valores citados é: 4997567718

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, por algum motivo, acho que o site mudou o valor de 98765 para 98 e de 100000 para 100, por isso que ele esta gerando os tais valores

Comment: Eu mudei porque o output estava grande demais. Não foi o site. O problema não é este. O algoritmo, e portanto, a resposta, estão errados.